# SBT execute code based on value

Tags: sbt

I want to do something like the following in SBT:

```
CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
  case Some((2, 11)) =>
  case Some((2, 10)) => 
}
```

But I don't want to assign that to anything, I simply want to run some code based on the value of the current cross version.

I could create a Task and then execute the task, but can I do this without needing the task?

Comment: When would you like this code to run (I mean at what time, load, by the way of another tasak, etc.)?

Comment: Just as part of the build I guess. So lets say when the default Compile phase runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've said you didn't want to create a task, but I would say that's the cleanest way of doing it, so I'll post it as one of the solutions anyway.

#### Depends on Compile

```
val printScalaVersion = taskKey[Unit]("Prints Scala version")

printScalaVersion := {
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, 11)) => println("2.11")
    case Some((2, 10)) => println("2.10")
    case _ => println("Other version")
  }
}

compile in Compile := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn printScalaVersion).value
```

#### Override the Compile Task

If you really wouldn't like to create new task, you could redefine the compile task and add your code there (I think it's not as clean as the solution above).

```
compile in Compile := {
  val analysis = (compile in Compile).value
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, 11)) => println("2.11")
    case Some((2, 10)) => println("2.10")
    case _ => println("Other version")
  }
  analysis
}
```

Comment: Why do sometimes people use taskKey and other times TaskKey?

Comment: Well `taskKey` is a macro and `TaskKey` is an object. If it's a question up to why, I don't know ;). When I'm speaking of `build.sbt` I usually go for `taskKey`, when `Build.scala` I go for `TaskKey`, but I think it doesn't really matter. The `taskKey` is shorter, as you don't have to specify the task name as it will pick it up from the `val`.

Comment: Ah yeah I see. taskKey is a macro that generates the name from the val. Ok cheers. And I like your solution. Using this task is nicer than I imagined.

Comment: Why is this a task not a mere setting?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I guess you're talking about `taskKey[Unit]("Prints Scala version")`. The OP said in the comments that he would like to run it by the way of compilation task. You cannot `dependOn` keys. Well if you think of it it makes sense, if keys are evaluated at load time, why would you need to depend on them? When your task runs they are already evaluated.

Comment: Right. After thinking about it, I think the other solution - Override the Compile Task - is what I was referring to.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski that one I dont get. Where would you put a setting in there?

Comment: `CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value)` gives you a value of the setting and you could define another setting to hold the value. With the new setting you could effectively do what you offered in Override.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski again, I think if that was a setting the code within the `case` would run at the build load time. The OP said he wanted to run the code at compile time. I could defer the execution by returning the function from the setting key, but still I'd have to override the `compile` and call it from there. That would be hardly simpler solution I believe. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52786/discussion-between-jacek-laskowski-and-lpiepiora)

Answer (score 0):

Just a small "enhancement" to what @lpiepiora offered.

There could be a setting that'd hold the value of `CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value)` as follows:

```
lazy val sv = settingKey[Option[(Int, Int)]]("")

sv := CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value)
```

With the setting:

```
> sv
[info] Some((2,10))
> ++ "2.9.3"
[info] Setting version to 2.9.3
[info] Set current project to projectA (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/scalaVersionSetting/)
> sv
[info] Some((2,9))
> ++ "2.10.4"
[info] Setting version to 2.10.4
[info] Set current project to projectA (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/scalaVersionSetting/)
> sv
[info] Some((2,10))
> ++ "2.11"
[info] Setting version to 2.11
[info] Set current project to projectA (in build file:/C:/dev/sandbox/scalaVersionSetting/)
> sv
[info] Some((2,11))
```

...and so on.

That would give a setting to `case` upon.

```
lazy val printScalaVersion = taskKey[Unit]("Prints Scala version")

printScalaVersion := {
  sv.value foreach println
}
```